# Cheerio - indent newly inserted element under sibling?

Tags: node.js, xml, cheerio, xliff

I am using cheerio to mutate a xml file in node. I am inserting the node/element `<target>` after `<source>` which works with the `insertAfter()` api in `oldEl.translation.insertAfter(msgSourceEl);`.

However, I loose my indention:

```
  <trans-unit id="title" datatype="html">
    <source>Login</source><target>iniciar sesión</target>
```

Is it possible, or is there a way, to indent the newly inserted `<target>iniciar sesión</target>` underneath the `<source>` element?

Comment: I don't think the library supports that. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/822. Best would be to find some XML formatter library and beautify the output after manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just fix the final XML indentation :

It is possible to use [`xml-beautifier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-beautifier) to achieve the human-readable indented XML

```
import beautify from 'xml-beautifier';
const HumanXML = beautify(XML);
console.log(HumanXML); // => will output correctly indented elements
```

---

## (EXTRA) No need for `Cheerio` :

In the following example we will be using [`xml2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to manipulate the XML as a JSON and then build it back to the original XML format

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = "<trans-unit id=\"title\" datatype=\"html\"><source>Login</source></trans-unit>"

xml2js.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    result["trans-unit"].target=["iniciar sessión"]
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
    console.log(xml)
});
```

**Final Output :**

```
<trans-unit id="title" datatype="html">
  <source>Login</source>
  <target>iniciar sessión</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I am sure you are doing this as part of a loop, so it shouldn't be hard to extrapolate the example to make it work . I suggest using [`underscore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore) for the usual (each, map, reduce, filter...)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) is an empty element, cheerio does not keep the `<source>Login</source>`. It converts it to `<source>Login`

So for demonstrating element indentation I will use a `<source2>` element.

As shown below, providing newlines and tabs as part of the given html solves the issue.

```js
let $ = require('cheerio').load(`
<trans-unit id="title" datatype="html">
    <source2>Login</source2>
</trans-unit>`)

$(`
    <target>iniciar sesión</target>`).insertAfter($('source2'));
console.log($.html('trans-unit'))
```

**output**

```html
<trans-unit id="title" datatype="html">
    <source2>Login</source2>
    <target>iniciar sesión</target>
</trans-unit>
```